# How can i make difficult for someone to discover my firebase url accessed from android?

Tags: android, firebase

I am making android app which authenticate anonymously, so how can i make difficult for other person to discover my firebase url that is accessed from my android app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exposing your Firebase URL is not a big security risk and it is necessary to expose it in order for the users to be able to interact with your database.

To properly protect your data, you should use a combination of authentication and authorization.

The first you'd do through [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which means you require your users to sign in with the app.

You'd then use this knowledge of who the users are to ensure they can only perform authorized operations on the data. For that you'd use the [security rules for the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

If you have those two in place, you can secure the data against malicious users and share the URL without fearing them.